# Client callbacks with protobuf-net.Grpc

Tags: grpc, protobuf-net

I'm currently working on replacing an old WCF client/server pairing with gRpc, and decided to use protobuf-net.Grpc as we've used protobuf-net extensively elsewhere in our codebase. I'm running into a bit of trouble with one particular portion however.

Part of the original service is a Subscribe method which uses IClientCallback to effectively send an event to the client. Looking at regular gRpc, it seems like this would be possible (though a bit hacky) using a server streaming method and storing the IServerStreamWriter object on the server, writing to it whenever we wanted to "fire an event".

For the life of me, however, I can't quite figure out how to do something similar in protobuf-net.Grpc with the IAsyncEnumerable return type. The closest I can figure is using Task.Wait in a loop and updating some shared collection when I want to "fire" the event, which the loop would then check for and yield return. This doesn't seem like it'd scale well, however, and there isn't really a great way to definitely unsubscribe when a client is no longer listening to events.

Is there some other/better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Channel<T>`, which can be tweaked via `AsAsyncEnumerable()` - which then essentially acts as a queue at the producer side, and a sequence at the consumer.